# Is it possible to create a grid layout in LibGDX that maps to an array?

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to create a grid type layout in LibGDX that will map to a 2d array. So if a user moves an object on the grid layout, it will check the array to see if the move is legal and then move the object in the layout and grid.

The only way I currently know how to do this, would be to simply calculate the current size of the screen and divide it up accordingly, and then store those values somewhere, but this seems rather tedious. Is there a simpler way of doing so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use an [ExtendViewport](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) with the virtual size of your grid to manage your camera. Then you will know that a movement of 1 equates to one grid space.

You can draw TextureRegions using widths and heights relative to this grid scale. Or if using Sprites you can set the width and height of all your Sprites relative to the grid scale when you load them.